# Is it possible to render a screen material transparent?

Tags: rendering

Is it possible to make a material that won't render or is transparent in the rendered PNG? Basically, I'm wanting to replace it with videos in After effects later without having to render out a whole animation in blender.

I'd want the blue screens to be transparent in the render.

[image: screen example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Holdout Shader. Don't forget to enable the transparent setting in the render settings → Film panel:

[image]

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I needed thank you so much!